Play sound when received FCM notification on background in Android 14
I'm encountering an issue with playing a ringtone in the background for my notifications on Android 14. Here's the flow: I receive notification data from FCM, create a silent notification channel, and display the notification. Then, I attempt to play the ringtone using Ringtone.play(). This works fine on Android versions below 14, but on Android 14, it plays the default notification sound, even though both the notification and the channel are configured to be silent.
Channel code
    private void checkAndCreateNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (mChannel == null) {
            String channelName = getString(R.string.app_name_short) + " Notifications";
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setDescription(channelName);
            mChannel.setSound(null, null);
        }
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
}

Notification code
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
    builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
    builder.setSound(null);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setTimeoutAfter(10000);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    builder.build().flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    builder.setChannelId(channelId);
    builder.setSilent(true);

Ringtone code
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    
    ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
    AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
            .build();
    ringtone.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes);
    ringtone.play();

